# Error on color substraction on build after laravel-mix update to 4.0.12

Tags: sass, laravel-mix

I noticed that sass build fails on color substraction after update to `laravel-mix@4.0.12`

My code in **app.scss**

```
.footer {
  background-color: #fefefe - #a0a0a0
}
```

My **webpack.mix.js**

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

const resourcesAssets = 'resources/assets/';
const dest = 'public/assets/';

mix
  .sass(`${resourcesAssets}scss/app.scss`, `${dest}css`);
```

On `laravel-mix@1.7.2` running `npm run prod` works properly, but now I got next error

```
 ERROR  Failed to compile with 2 errors22:16:34

 error  in ./resources/sass/app.scss

Module build failed (from ./node_modules/css-loader/index.js):
ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js):

undefined
                     ^
      Undefined operation "#fefefe - #a0a0a0".
    background-color: #fefefe - #a0a0a0
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  stdin 2:23  root stylesheet
      in C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-test-mix\resources\sass\app.scss (line 2, column 23)
    at runLoaders (C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-test-mix\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:301:20)
    at C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-test-mix\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:364:11
    at C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-test-mix\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:230:18
    at context.callback (C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-test-mix\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:111:13)
    at render (C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-test-mix\node_modules\sass-loader\lib\loader.js:52:13)
    at Function.$2 (C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-test-mix\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:25378:48)
    at vB.$2 (C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-test-mix\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:16223:16)
    at tz.ve (C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-test-mix\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:9275:42)
    at tz.vd (C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-test-mix\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:9277:32)
    at ic.uo (C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-test-mix\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:8583:46)
    at t6.$0 (C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-test-mix\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:8728:7)
    at Object.eu (C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-test-mix\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:1569:80)
    at aj.bd (C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-test-mix\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:8646:3)
    at is.bd (C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-test-mix\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:8576:25)
    at is.cF (C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-test-mix\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:8563:6)
    at oy.cF (C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-test-mix\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:8350:35)
    at Object.o (C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-test-mix\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:1442:19)
    at C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-test-mix\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:5284:51
    at w0.a (C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-test-mix\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:1453:71)
    at w0.$2 (C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-test-mix\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:8365:23)
    at uC.$2 (C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-test-mix\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:8360:25)
    at tz.ve (C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-test-mix\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:9275:42)
    at tz.vd (C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-test-mix\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:9277:32)
    at ic.uo (C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-test-mix\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:8583:46)
    at t6.$0 (C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-test-mix\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:8728:7)
    at Object.eu (C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-test-mix\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:1569:80)
    at aj.bd (C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-test-mix\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:8646:3)
    at is.bd (C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-test-mix\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:8576:25)
    at is.cF (C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-test-mix\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:8563:6)
    at oy.cF (C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-test-mix\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:8350:35)
    at Object.o (C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-test-mix\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:1442:19)
    at C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-test-mix\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:5835:52
    at w0.a (C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-test-mix\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:1453:71)
    at w0.$2 (C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-test-mix\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:8365:23)
    at uC.$2 (C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-test-mix\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:8360:25)
    at tz.ve (C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-test-mix\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:9275:42)
```

How can I fix this problem without setting up previously calculated value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Color arithmetic was [deprecated in dart-sass 4](https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/2144). 
They recommend you (in a harsh way) to use [color functions](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html). 
I rather like [this color functions visual summary](http://jackiebalzer.com/color). You are probably looking for darken(color,%) in your code.